# Transport from Ottawa airport to University area?

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation, night-transport, ottawa, yow

What options for transportation from Ottawa international airport ([YOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottawa_Macdonald%E2%80%93Cartier_International_Airport)) to the [University of Ottawa area](http://maps.uottawa.ca)?

Interested in daytime hours but also middle-of-the-night options (2 AM).

Other than renting a car, what are the options specifically? (Bus, train, light rail, etc.)

Comment: FYI, there is a new light rail line from airport to university, but is not yet operational, in testing, behind schedule from its 2018 planned launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is bus 97 running from the Airport to close to the University of Ottawa:](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Ottawa-Airport-YOW/University-of-Ottawa)

> [image]

The bus runs all day and night [according to OC Transpo's own planner](http://plan.octranspo.com/plan/RouteSchedules?Date=2016-5-25&RouteDirection=Direction1&RoutePublicIdentifier=97&ShowOptions=false&SelectedStopsIdentifiers=) (contradicting what Rome2Rio seems to suggest above).

Comment: Tip: Every bus that arrives at the airport is inexplicably labeled “Out Of Service”. Get onboard anyways. Otherwise they simply drive away without a word. The 97 is the only route at the airport, so you cannot go wrong. Costs $3.50, but they’ll accept a five dollar bill (without giving change).

Answer (score 2):

There's an all day (and night) bus (97) service with, as far as I can see a stop at uOttawa (Nicholas st. and Laurier st.)

There are also taxi service at the airport. and there's also Uber.